# Character references (Entities) to UTF Characters

Tags: java, php, coldfusion, utf-8

I am facing a character reference problem. My CKEditor converts the special characters to corresponding Entities (in CKEditor I can't change the settings.) And this looks like as under.

```
"&#214;" => "Ö"
"&#246;" => "ö"
"&#196;" => "Ä"
"&#228;" => "ä"
"&#220;" => "Ü"
"&#252;" => "ü"
```

Now In my Java, PHP or Coldfusion script I want again to replace all the Entities with special characters. 
Is there any method available for such replacements?

Answer (score 2):

For Java, the Apache Commons [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHTML(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) method understands all standard entity attributes in a number of versions of HTML, including the numeric ones.

---

By the way, this has nothing to do with UTF-8.  What you will get will be a Java String which contains a modified form of UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP, try [`html_entity_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)